# Eclipse Photon Installation failed with an error

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to install the latest version of eclipse today and it showed "Installation failed with an error. See the log." and this error log when I clicked on install. So can anyone please tell what's the problem?

My os version : Windows10

My jdk version : jdk-10.0.2

My jre version : jre1.8.0_181

拒绝访问 means Access Denied

Here is the log:

```
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_181-b13
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.photon
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.10.0.v20180706-1242, build=3615, branch=e20723a0a43b5625f801a1d1b3147fc611b51751
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.10.0.v20180714-0556, build=3615, branch=e20723a0a43b5625f801a1d1b3147fc611b51751
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.10.0.v20180706-1242, build=3615, branch=e20723a0a43b5625f801a1d1b3147fc611b51751
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Photon))
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Offline = false
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Mirrors = true
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Resolving 26 requirements from 3 repositories to F:\Software\java-photon\eclipse
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement epp.package.java [4.8.0,4.9.0)
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.8.0,4.9.0)
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.8.0,4.9.0)
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/photon
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2018-08-12 16:59:32] org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\.p2\profiles.info.temp (拒绝访问。)（Access Denied)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.save(PersistentMap.java:311)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.addElement(PersistentMap.java:155)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.createProfile(AgentImpl.java:439)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.BundlePoolImpl$1.doCreateProfile(BundlePoolImpl.java:191)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileCreatorImpl.create(ProfileCreatorImpl.java:403)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.getProfile(P2TaskImpl.java:824)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:675)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3334)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3262)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3243)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3143)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1111)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\.p2\profiles.info.temp (拒绝访问。)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.save(PersistentMap.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.addElement(PersistentMap.java:155)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.createProfile(AgentImpl.java:439)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.BundlePoolImpl$1.doCreateProfile(BundlePoolImpl.java:191)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileCreatorImpl.create(ProfileCreatorImpl.java:403)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.getProfile(P2TaskImpl.java:824)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:675)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3334)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3262)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3243)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3143)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
  ... 1 more

[2018-08-12 16:59:32]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like during installation, it tried to write to some files that don't exist, or have permission modifiers.
Check the directories and make sure that the files are acessable and/or exist. You can also try updating JDK, JRE, or just try the update again.

Or, as a last resort, uninstall Eclipse entirely, and reinstall it.

Hope this helped.